# Find the first numeric value in a column in Pandas using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of a header of a variable number of lines, then it has several columns of numeric data

The dataframe looks something like this (I've skipped a bunch of rows, but it's basically the same):

| Index | Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 | Unnamed: 4 | Unnamed: 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | Job No: 21-05-23384 | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 1 | NaN | Client: Bob Canada | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 2 | NaN | Project: Uncle 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 3 | NaN | Sounding ID: SCPT21 | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 4 | NaN | Date: 04-Dec-2021 | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 14 | Depth (m) | Header | Header | Header | Header |  |
| 15 | 0.92 | 0.90 | NaN | NaN | NaN |  |
| 16 | 1.92 | 1.90 | 245 | 1.34 | 55 |  |

All I want to get is the index of the row the first value is in, 15. I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the first row with a number in _any_ column, or just that first non-Index column?

Comment: Sorry, first row with a number in the first column (Unnamed:0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my mind, the most logical way is to treat the Unnamed: 0 column rows as strings, return the first character of each string and determine if the character is numeric or not with isnumeric(). This will return either True or False in a new column.

```
df['numeric'] = df['Unnamed: 0'].astype(str).str[0].str.isnumeric()
```

Next, I would take all the indexes where the numeric column is True, assign the index values to a list and take the first value from that list:

```
idx = df.index[df['numeric']].tolist()[0]
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Just for my own clarity, df['numeric'] is a mask, which will be true where the first character in the cell is numeric? Then that is dumped into a list, from which we get the first position, which is the index of the first numeric row?

Comment: Yep, you pretty much nailed it :)

Comment: If, like me, you couldn't see the significance of the `str[0]` bit so planned on getting rid of it...don't. Without it, the code will work correctly on ints but not floats

Comment: Also worth saying: NaNs and NAs evaluate as False, as they're converted to the strings 'NaN', 'NA', which aren't numeric